# How does a USB 2.0 Wall Charger negotiate current output?

Tags: usb, charger

I'm trying to use a mobile phone charger for my projects, and want a high current output. I have read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/how-to-get-more-than-100ma-from-a-usb-port), however my measurements show something else.

[Here](http://komposter.com.ua/documents/BC1.2_FINAL.pdf) is a link to the Battery Charging Specification Rev. 1.2.

> 1.4.7 Dedicated Charging Port
>
> A Dedicated Charging Port (DCP) is a downstream port on a device that
> outputs power through a USB connector, but is not capable of
> enumerating a downstream device. A DCP shall source \$I_{DCP}\$ at an average
> voltage of \$V_{CHG}\$. A DCP shall short the D+ line to the D- line.

[image]

I verified on three different chargers, and all read \$R_{DCP\_DAT}\$ as ~1.5 Ohms. Now, if there is a short between the D+ and D-, there is no detection on the charging port side, and the charger should always output \$I_{DCP}\$ {0.5 - 5.0A max} on the VBUS line - is this correct?

I tested the current output of three chargers, but they are all completely different.

**Charger 1 - Nokia**

Rated current output: 1.3A

Measured current output: 1.34A

**Charger 2 - Asus**

Rated current output: 2.0A

Measured current output: 0.7A - 1.1A (unstable)

**Charger 3 - HTC**

Rated current output: 1A

Measurent current output: 0.1A

If all these dedicated charging ports have no current negotiation, how come only one charger is showing it's rated output?

N.B All three chargers can charge a mobile phone in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: How were you measuring the current output? What load did you connect? If you just put an ammeter directly across the output, that's not a valid measurement - the supply designer did not expect someone to short its output. It might even damage the charger.

Comment: @pericynthion I put a few 10 ohm resistors in parallel, enough to draw their maximum load current.

Comment: The way it works, as I recall, is that the charging device needs to sense input voltage and back-off if it droops below some threshold. So the charger and chargee negotiate by way of their V-I curve. The details are specified. I don't think there is a requirement that the DCP supply 5A. I think the minimum is 1.5A. So devices which draw less than 1.5 don't need to back-off.

Answer (score 8):

> there is no detection on the charging port side, and the charger should always output IDCPIDCP {0.5 - 5.0A max} on the VBUS line - is this correct?

I don't understand this completely, because [the BC spec](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/) is confusing to read, but yes, dedicated chargers (DCP) short the D+ and D- together to indicate what they are.  This doesn't indicate any particular current available, though, it just says that it's a DCP.  Different chargers supply different amounts of current.

The charger has no brain in it; it just supplies 5 V until the current draw is too great, and then its voltage starts to droop:

[image: DCP Required Operating Range]

It's the "portable device" (PD) which has to be smart about limiting its own current draw from the DCP to stay within the dark region of the plot.  So it can try to draw up to 1.5 A, but if the charger voltage drops below 2 V at 0.5 A, then you can't draw any more than 0.5 A from it.

> For a dedicated charger or USB
>   charger, the current limit is determined by loading the
>   adapter. When the adapter’s output voltage starts to
>   collapse, it is an indication that the current limit of the
>   device is reached. - [MAX8895 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8895V-MAX8895Y.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, your answer also led to me an explanation for how BC 1.2 could change I_DCP to 5 A without breaking things: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/497836/233001

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this answer will solve your question, but Apple does a similar thing with their wall chargers to make sure that the devices are not being charged too quickly. To accomplish this, the chargers have a voltage divider circuit comprised of 2 resistors that gives a reference voltage to one or both of the data pins. Inside the iPhone, there is additional circuitry that reads the voltage on the data pins from the voltage divider.

Here is a diagram of an "Apple Compatible" charger featuring the voltage divider that I was talking about:

[image: Apple Compatible Charger]

I would assume that Apple has different voltage dividers for different rated chargers. This way, a phone can tell if it can safely charge itself if the reference voltage is under 2v for example.

Comment: I'm quite sure that both Apple and Samsung used circuits that detected an Apple phone reliable (Apple charger) or a Samsung phone reliable (Samsung charger), so an Apple charger with a Samsung phone would be reliable and slow, and a Samsung charger with an Apple phone would be reliable and slow, and each phone with the right charger was about twice the speed. Since this was non-standard, they both tried hard not to give more power except to their own phones.

Answer (score 3):

The question is ill-posed, conceptually.

Usual wall (and BC1.1/1.2) **chargers do not negotiate anything**. They only **"advertise"** their capability by means of some signature on D+/D- wires. It is **the DEVICE that decides** to take maximum necessary current based on detected signature and the state of internal battery.

As other respondents noted, there is "Chinese signature" (with D+ shorted to D-), there is "Apple signature" with certain combination of voltages (using ~40k-70k resistors), there could be BC1.2 with sequential handshake. Due to total awkwardness and complexity associated with BC1.2, this signature can be hardly found ever.

In modern days things can be different with advent of new Power Delivery Specification (PD), where "provider" (charger) actively advertises its capability with "consumer" through a serial communication channel with a fairly sophisticated protocol. Originally the VBUS wire was thought for this purpose in PD1.1 (the idea is now abandoned), and now the CC pins in Type-C connector are used for this purpose.

Comment: Does this mean that PD 2.0 only works over Type-C connectors? I've read elsewhere that the USB 3.0, PD and Type-C specs are completely independent, and that Type-C with electronically marked cables can only add the benefit of allowing 5 A instead of 3 A current over the cable (besides additional data wires, for alternate modes). I concluded that PD can work over Type-A, too. I only have access to a PD adapter with a fixed Type-C plug. All other chargers are QC 2.0 (Samsung) or unknown. This is so confusing.

Comment: @ygoe, if I understood correctly, PD over type-A requires a special cable, though I have never seen one. PD over type-C, at 3 A at most, works with any compliant cable.

Comment: "D+ shorted to D-" is from the USB Battery Charging specification.  Not sure what you mean by "Chinese signature"

Comment: @endolith, long before the BC1.2 was crafted into existence, the Chinese government has established the D+-short-D- standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_external_power_supply#Charger_and_interface_standard_in_China

Comment: @Ale..chenski Interesting.  [4.2.3.2
Interface requirement of the charger side](https://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/PI_596/PDF/PowerInt_ChinaUSB.pdf?redirected=1) "D+ and D- should be short-circuit and does not connect to 
any part of the charger inside the charger."

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible the charger is implementing data contact detection (to ensure full insertion- the power contacts mate first).. suggest you try connecting the D+ to a plausible VDP_SRC voltage.

Comment: It says VDP_SRC should be 0.5 - 0.7V and source 250uA. Will a resistor divider between VBUS and GND be okay, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Diode and a resistor maybe.

Comment: Still the same result.. I also noticed the current doesn't increase linearly. ie. 10ohm resistor = 0.43A, 10 || 10 ohm resistors = 0.75, 10 || 10 || 10 resistors = 1.0A

Comment: What's happening to the voltage? How much voltage is your ammeter dropping?

Comment: Don't have a second meter with me right now, will let you know  once I do

Answer (score -1):

I've seen charger using AD42011D having only 2 wires to connect to device, maybe a data loopback at the usb male. Good thing about this IC is that it is able to detect full charge and will provide trickle charge when full, so you will not overcharge your device. I couldn't find the datasheet but very simple circuit with minimal components.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you could track down at least a datasheet for the part, I couldn't seem to find a datasheet or even mention of the existence of a AD42011 are you sure that's the correct part number?