# Learn to design cell phone charger

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, charger

I have my final project for my undergraduate that I want to make a cell phone charger with:

1. Output voltage: 5 V (constant)
2. Output current: 0 - 3 A (can be adjust)

The purpose of the current can be adjustable is that I want it can makes like I can charge the battery (e. g. 2000mAh) with 2 A that it just take 1 hour for fast charge the battery, when I want that slower than 1 hour, I make it 2000mAh with 1 A so it can be full charged in 2 hour. I found the "ring choke converter" like mostly of chinese made-up charger. Is RCC suitable for this design or any type of switching power supply?

Comment: I’m not aware of any battery chemistry with 5 V peak voltage so I assume you mean USB. In that case you can’t just adjust the current since there is a negotiation between phone and charger about the current.

Comment: See here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130559/how-does-a-usb-2-0-wall-charger-negotiate-current-output/189628

Answer (score 0):

Cell phones generally use a Lithium-Ion battery.

Lithium-Ion batteries should **never** be charged from a 5 V supply with an adjustable current limit. Lithium-Ion batteries need to be charged by a **proper** Lithium-Ion battery charger circuit. This circuit charges the battery to (usually) 4.2 V with a current depending on the voltage (and thus charge-state) of the battery and of course the battery's capacity.

When a Lithium-Ion battery is almost empty and also when it is almost full it needs to be charged with a small current. Only when the charge level is between 40 % and 70% (these numbers can vary) is charging with the maximum current safe to do.

So your assumption that you can charge a cell phone battery like you're suggesting this is wrong, it doesn't work like that and if you did proceed you run the risk of damaging the battery.

It is unclear if you are trying to make something which is fed from mains voltage. I hope not because that is **very dangerous** and you **must** know what you're doing before you can do this safely. Usually only engineers **with some years of experience in that field** know what is required. So don't make anything mains connected, for your own (and other people's) safety.